# <button> has excess margin after setting padding, margin, border to 0

Tags: html, css

The example below shows a `<button>` element whose parent's height is not the height of the button. What's the best way to remove this excess height while remaining semantic and also keeping the `<button>` inline?

If I set the button to `display:block` then the excess height is removed. If I set the parent's font-size to 0, then it is also removed. If I change the `<button>` to a `<div>` element, then it is fixed as well. Should I just not be semantic?

I have tested this under the stable version of Google Chrome.

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <button class='box'></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<button>` is an `inline-replaced` element, so you just need to set the `line-height` property in CSS.

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 0;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <button class='box'></button>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.  If you need any additional help, please comment below.

Comment: This is the same as setting font-size to 0, yeah? Is this better than just using a <div>? It feels weird to be fighting CSS so much in the name of being semantic.

Comment: No, it's not the same as setting the font-size to 0, as your button's text would be VERY hard to read, lol.  I'm not sure why you are using this, but if this is what it's going to look like in the end, I would definitely consider using a `block-level` element.

Comment: Well, I can reset the font-size on the <button> element. Setting font-size to 0 is a common workaround for the padding between inline elements. I'm mostly opposed to your solution because the fix is applied to the parent element rather than the 'culprit.' I feel like styling a <div> might be better.. but it IS a button which is clicked so I was trying to be as clear as possible with my HTML.

Comment: I see.  Setting `font-size` to zero would be applied to the parent element rather than the 'culprit', would it not?

Comment: Why want you to brake your `font-size`?? `line-height: 0` just cut bottom and captions are still readable.

Comment: Yes, @vp_arth.  Sean, `line-height` would probably be the way to go in this case (and in most).

Comment: Yeah, it would. :( And doing some reading on MDN, it appears that the line-height fix isn't correct according to spec -- just that it was implemented. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Browser_compatibility Assuming I'm reading that correctly?

Comment: Also `.outer{height: 30px;}` should fix the issue. But it is additional harcoded dependency..

Comment: @vp_arth I'm not trying to couple the elements together like that. I know of many fixes for it. I just was investigating which would be most flexible as the application scales. Anywho, I went ahead and did line-height fix. Thanks +1 :)

Comment: Yep.  Go with `line-height`.  That's the most flexible.

Comment: Aha, simple adding text to button, fix this issue, even `:after{content}` works...

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened, because empty text don't rendered and baseline makes margin.
You can just add the text to your button, then it will correct rendered.
Also hardcoded `vertical-align` should make the trick.

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
.fix {
  vertical-align: sub;
}
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h5>Initial issue</h5>
<div class='outer'>
  <button class='box'></button>
</div>
<hr/>
<h5>Add a text</h5>
<div class='outer'>
  <button class='box'>+</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<h5>Fix by vertical-align</h5>
<div class='outer'>
  <button class='box fix'></button>
</div>
```

Comment: The vertical-align fix is a great solution because it doesn't rely on a parent wrapper. :)